# Explanation to Rabin Karp from CLRS

Tags: algorithm, clrs, rabin-karp

I've been reading the `Rabin Karp` algorithm from `Introduction To Algorithms`. Everything makes sense except the following.

```
In general, with a d-ary alphabet {0, 1, . . ., d - 1}, we choose q so
that dq fits within a computer word
```

I don't understand what's a `computer word` and what's the significance of fitting `dq within a computer word` in the context of this algorithm.

I read somewhere it is something related to single-precision math but I don't understand `single-precision math` either.

Can anyone break these terminologies down? Thank you.

Comment: A `computer word` is an ambiguous term, it could mean byte, but it also could mean (and I think it is the right sense here) `processor word`, which represents the size of a processor word (usually 32 or 64 bits). Single precision usualy refers to the `float` type, as opposed to double precision, called `double`. These terms are really hardware-specific in the first case, implementation and language-dependent in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

A [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) is the standard "type" your computer is dealing with.

In practice a word corresponds to 64 bits (32 bits for older computers).